# How do I weatherstrip the bottom side of my sliding patio door?

Tags: doors, patio, weatherstripping

The bottom side looks like in the picture below. THe second picture shows you the door and the corner that was zoomed in the first picture.
The verticals have their weatherstrips in place. It is just the bottom one that seems to be missing.

Can anybody figure out how I can install a weatherstrip to cover that 4mm gap?

[image]
[image]
<sup>*Click for larger images.*</sup>

Comment: Can you take some pictures in the daytime?  Also, one further back with an arrow to the area in question?

Comment: That is going to be difficult because I leave when it is dark and I come back when it is dark. I will try it over the weekend. What you see above is the bottom side of the inside door, the zoom in picture is taken at ground level close to that corner that is in the middle of the picture